# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Query Excluding Records

Tags: mysql, join, select, where-clause, group-concat

I'm having a bit of an issue with my query below.  I'm pulling data from a few tables and using the GROUP_CONCAT feature for a few rows.  The GROUP_CONCAT pulls custom field data based on `requests.REQUEST_ID`.  However, not every `REQUEST_ID` has an entry in `TABLE_fields_data`.  Therefore, this element in my WHERE clause is causing an issue: `data.REQUEST_ID=requests.REQUEST_ID`.

I still want to pull the data from `TABLE_requests` even if there are no corresponding values in `TABLE_fields_data`.  With my current query, the data is being completely omitted.

I've tried IFNULL in my GROUP_CONTACT statements but that didn't seem to make a difference.  I've tried figuring out how to do an IF statement in the `data.REQUEST_ID=requests.REQUEST_ID` WHERE clause but haven't gotten that to work either.  Based on my sample data below, the query would not return the request ID 6000002.

Really stuck on this and would be grateful for any help!

```
TABLE_requests
+------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| REQUEST_ID | REQUEST_STATUS | USER_ID | DATE_CREATE         |
+------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| 6000001    | COMPLETE       | 3000001 | 2020-06-01 11:15:16 |
+------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| 6000002    | COMPLETE       | 3000001 | 2020-06-02 16:14:11 |
+------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| 6000003    | PENDING        | 3000001 | 2020-06-03 12:11:11 |
+------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+

TABLE_fields
+----------+------+---------------+
| FIELD_ID | TYPE | LABEL_en      |
+----------+------+---------------+
| 1        | TEXT | Student Name  |
+----------+------+---------------+
| 2        | TEXT | Student Grade |
+----------+------+---------------+
| 3        | TEXT | Course        |
+----------+------+---------------+

TABLE_fields_data
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| DATA_ID | REQUEST_ID | FIELD_ID | DATA       |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1       | 6000001    | 1        | John Smith |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| 2       | 6000001    | 2        | 1st Grade  |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+

SELECT 
    requests.REQUEST_ID, requests.REQUEST_STATUS, requests.USER_ID, requests.DATE_CREATE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(data.FIELD_ID SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(fields.TYPE SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fields.LABEL_en SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_LABEL, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(data.DATA SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_DATA
FROM TABLE_requests AS requests, TABLE_fields_data AS data, TABLE_fields AS fields
WHERE requests.REQUEST_STATUS='COMPLETE' AND data.REQUEST_ID=requests.REQUEST_ID AND fields.FIELD_ID=data.FIELD_ID GROUP BY requests.REQUEST_ID;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using INNER joins (old style) but what you need is LEFT joins:

```
SELECT 
    requests.REQUEST_ID, requests.REQUEST_STATUS, requests.USER_ID, requests.DATE_CREATE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(data.FIELD_ID SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(fields.TYPE SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_TYPE, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fields.LABEL_en SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_LABEL, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(data.DATA SEPARATOR '||') AS CUSTOM_FIELD_DATA
FROM TABLE_requests AS requests
LEFT JOIN TABLE_fields_data AS data ON data.REQUEST_ID = requests.REQUEST_ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE_fields AS fields ON fields.FIELD_ID = data.FIELD_ID
WHERE requests.REQUEST_STATUS = 'COMPLETE' 
GROUP BY requests.REQUEST_ID;
```